# PlusClient.OnPeopleLoadedListenter cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, google-plus

For Google plus login in android app, with
`com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient` package and using the above listener shows error.
Want to get userId after login.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you haven't added the google-play-services_lib library project to your own project.  Or possibly that the version you have imported is out of date.

Take a look at these instructions in section 2:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

And make sure that the version of 'Extras > Google Play Services' you have in your Android SDK Manager is at least version 6.